# Enums with functions as values

Tags: python, enums

Let's start with a simple function and put it inside an `Enum`:

```py
def foo():
    return 'foo'

from enum import Enum

class EnumWithFuncs(Enum):
    FOO = foo
```

And we are going to compare it with a "regular" `Enum` of strings:

```py
class EnumWithStrings(Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
```

My Python 3.8.9 accepts both of these definitions, but `EnumWithFuncs` behaves very differently:

```py
# first experiment: does 'FOO' field exist? It does and the function is callable!
>>> EnumWithStrings.FOO
<EnumWithStrings.FOO: 'foo'>
>>> EnumWithFuncs.FOO
<function foo at 0x104b54550>
>>> EnumWithFuncs.FOO()
'foo'
# second experiment: trying to list all elements of the Enum and FOO is gone!
>>> list(EnumWithStrings)
[<EnumWithStrings.FOO: 'foo'>]
>>> list(EnumWithFuncs)
[]
# third experiment: 'FOO' doesn't exist in dir() either
>>> dir(EnumWithStrings)
['FOO', '__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
>>> dir(EnumWithFuncs)
['__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? How can I use functions as values inside an `Enum`?

Comment: `EnumWithFuncs.foo` is not an instance of `EnumWithFuncs`; it's just a function. You've really  just created a (poorly defined) instance method that works because you are calling it from the class itself, rather than an instance of the class.

Comment: @chepner But what's the right way to do it?

Comment: The author of the `enum` class often answers `enum`-related questions here; I'm waiting for them to write a clearer answer than I'll probably be able to provide.

Comment: Here's the [relevant section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations) of the documentation: "The rules for what is allowed are as follows: names that start and end with a single underscore are reserved by enum and cannot be used; all other attributes defined within an enumeration will become members of this enumeration, with the exception of special methods (`__str__()`, `__add__()`, etc.), **descriptors (methods are also descriptors)**, and variable names listed in `_ignore_`."

Comment: @chepner That same section also says *"enumerations can have arbitrary values"*, so looks like that's not quite accurate.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's why the documentation uses the term "exception".

Comment: Not in that sentence, not even in that paragraph or the next.

Comment: @KellyBundy: see the redirected question for the details, but it boils down to objects that have a `__get__` method not being converted to members.